# Why is my navigation not vertical when using Fullpage.js?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm implementing [Fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs)

I believe I've followed the documentation properly however, the navigation seems to be stuck in horizontal format even though I've selected the vertical navigation.

I'll post my code below, but here is a [live version](http://mrthomason.com).

**HTML**

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            css3: true,
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            keyboardScrolling: true,
            controlArrows: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

The CSS is being pulled from the [source files](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.css) which I haven't touched, and it's after my stylesheet so there should be no overriding issues. Console log is showing no issues.

I've also noticed that the first nav dot has more padding on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"style.css" has conflict with "jquery.fullPage.css".
[image]

Comment: I have done. Seem to be blind to the where I'm going wrong. I've updated the [live exmaple](http://mrthomason.com/) but the issue remains,

Comment: "live example" need password, I can't enter

Comment: oops, password removed.

Comment: "style.css" has conflict with "jquery.fullPage.css". Can you delete "style.css"?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my non specific `li` and `ul`'s in my stylesheet were overriding the fullpage.js stylesheets. For example when I replace my `li:hover` with `.divName li:hover` it fixed the problem.

One thing that is confusing me how this happened, especially since the DOM was reading the `fullpage.css` file last.